# Free .NET library to play flash content without Internet exlorer needed

Tags: .net, flash

I'm working on desktop application that should open remote flash object with flashvars parameters.

I tried with shockwave flash object library, but seems that flashvars option is not working. Also i have temporary solution with webbrowser control and making flash object filled. But webbrowser require Internet explorer with flash player installed. I can install flash player with my setup installer, but can't install flash in internet explorer automatically.

So i need some simple solution, where users do not have to install anything, i'm looking for some free flash library with flashvars option.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use [Adobe Air](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/articles/packaging-air-apps-desktop.html) & deploy it as a windows app?

Comment: Because i have desktop application, and flash object is just one feature of the .net application.

Comment: U want to deliver flash content. But why do you want to focus on the 5% users who do not have flash?? I think you should re think about taking so much pain..

Comment: It's not problem in flash installed, it's problem with Internet explorer having flash installed.

Because .net webbrowser control is using IE, IE must have flash content installed and enabled. And that do not have 50% of users.